# Erro programa matriz em C

Tags: c#, c, c++

Estou iniciando agora na programação em C e estou com um problema no meu programa em C. O problema é que a matriz printada aparece toda zerada.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    int main (){
        float m[4][4];
        int i, j;

        for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<4;j++){
                m[i][j]=0;
         }
        }
        for(i=0;i<4;i++){
            for(j=0;j<4;j++){
                printf("%d", m[i][j]);
         }
                printf("\n");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Boa a resposta abaixo, agregando conhecimento, olhe este link: https://www.clubedohardware.com.br/forums/topic/1166436-preencher-matriz-usando-for-e-dowhile/ para mais exemplos

Comment: Ena tanta linguagem *taggada*. Esqueceste-te de `c--` e `d` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá. Sua matriz está aparecendo zerada porque você está zerando os elementos aqui: `m[i][j]=0;` . Ponha valores diferentes de zero nessa linha que estará tudo resolvido. No exemplo abaixo, eu inseri valores na matriz iguais ao produto dos índices (apenas para demonstração).

```
int main (){
float m[4][4];
int i, j;

for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<4;j++){
        m[i][j]=i*j;
 }
}
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    for(j=0;j<4;j++){
        printf("%d", m[i][j]);
 }
        printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: muito obrigada!

Comment: fico feliz em ajudar

Comment: @use_-44-18 marca a resposta como certa pra mostrar que sua pergunta foi respondida =]